# Parse XML rows to json string

Tags: php, xml, json

I need to get the value between two XML tags on different lines. The XML file is multi level. For example I need every data between `<student>` and `</student>` this data ill put in a JSON string in the database:

```
<SchoolRoster>
   <Student>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>14</age>
      <course>
         <math>A</math>
         <english>B</english>
      </course>
      <course>
         <government>A+</government>
      </course>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <age>13</age>
      <course>
         <gym>A</gym>
         <geography>incomplete</geography>
      </course>
   </Student>
</SchoolRoster>
```

I tried the following:

```
$entities = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

preg_match_all('/<Student>(.*?)<\/Student>/s', $entities, $json);

$obj =  json_encode($json);
```

This only returns

```
[]
```

Any thoughts? It should return a JSON string.

I hope I explained it clear enough. Real beginner here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run a `preg_match_all` against a `SimpleXMLElement` object.

Use a foreach loop to iterate over all students and create a simple array which you then can encode as a JSON string.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXmlStr);

$studentsArr = array();

foreach($xml->student as $student) {
   // Dump student data in temp array
}

echo json_encode($studentsArr);
```

Comment: I'm using a foreach ($entities as $entitiesinfo):

$entities = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); is above the loop. The pregmatch and the json encode is within the loop.

Comment: You have to use `foreach ($entities->Student as $entitiesinfo)` to get the data for each Student. And again: You can't use `preg_match*` against any object. Just scalar data types.

Comment: Thanks! :) Is there a way to put all the data from student in one array at once? This is a demo XML file, the real XML file contains about 100+ tags on sometimes 2-3 nested levels below student. I'm totally new to XML and how to work with it.

Comment: No you have to cast each value of student's data to a scalar datatype and add it to the array.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of! Thanks for the quick help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I run your example it gives me:

```
[[],[]]
```

However as has already been answered, you can not run [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) here on the **SimpleXMLElement**, at least not in a useful manner. Instead it's far easier, as [the **SimpleXMLElement** ships with an expression matcher](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) in your case:

```
$entities = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$json = $entities->xpath('//Student');

$obj = json_encode($json);
```

It's called xpath, and it's the query/expression language for XML. Regular expressions are for general strings, not for XML specifically.

Alternatively you can also use [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) in your case:

```
$entities = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$json = iterator_to_array($entities->Student, false);

$obj = json_encode($json);
```

Both examples would produce the same outcome, which would give you (pretty printed):

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "14",
        "course": [
            {
                "math": "A",
                "english": "B"
            },
            {
                "government": "A+"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": "13",
        "course": {
            "gym": "A",
            "geography": "incomplete"
        }
    }
]
```